# How to set up Opportunistic Encryption on Firefox 37?

Tags: firefox, osx-yosemite

I just read about Opportunistic Encryption for Firefox 37, but I am a n00b and don't know how to set it up. Can anyone provide instructions on specifically how to do it on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

You need HTTP v2 to use OE. AFAIK, neither NGINX nor Apache currently support v2 out of the box.

UPDATE: There are a few servers available right now that can be used. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) maintains a partial list of compliance.

What appears to be a fuller list exists on the [HTTP/2 pages on Github](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations).

It is fair to say support is pretty thin right now. Not surprising since the full RFC hasn't yet been published so HTTP/2 is still only a proposal right now.

If you want to play, it looks like Node.JS has support via the [node-http2 library](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2) and so it should be fairly easy to run up your own server.

Comment: Fair enough, is there any way to do it at all at this point?

Comment: @GrokSrc - Do what?  Firefox is client side.  It should just be enabled, it just won't be used more then likely, because the major server clients don't support it out of the box.

Comment: According to this it looks like a proxy server can be set up: http://bitsup.blogspot.it/2015/03/opportunistic-encryption-for-firefox.html?m=1

Comment: Not quite I'm afraid, that is how to configure things but you still need an HTTP/2 compliant server.

Comment: @GrokSrc - Sure;  The browser ( the client ) can connect to the proxy server over `HTTP/2 AltSvc`;  If you have nothing to connect the proxy server to ( the website ) that supports `HTTP/2 AltSvc` then it would just connect using another standard in theory.  The feature you asked about is enabled by default if I am not mistaken.